# How to display data in grid view using caml query?

Tags: html, web, design, editor

i can read the data from the list but unable to get in a table means gridview using caml query.I read the data using sp.js in JSOM

Comment: One way is to create a table like structure dynamically in html using the retrieved data. And other way is you can ready made plugins and just bind the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datatables to achieve the same:
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/deepObjects.html